# Stuck in emergency mode after cloning my system with clonezilla

Tags: troubleshooting, system-recovery, clonezilla

I cloned my installation from a 240GB SATA SSD to a 500GB NVMe SSD using Clonezilla. The cloning was completed successfully, except for a failure with  `initrd` (unfortauntely I don't remember the actual error). After rebooting I manage to get to right before the login screen and then I'm kicked into emergency mode. I already checked  `/etc/fstab` and the UUIDs of the drive are correct. I tried running  `update-initramfs -u` but that didn't help. I'm sorry for not providing more accurate debugging info, but I don't even know where to look for it. If anyone needs some debug logs please tell me where to find them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, answering for anyone that might encounter the same issue.

My fstab also had my storage drive in it and I didn't know the system wouldn't boot unless it detected all drives in the file. Make sure to comment out or delete any drives that are not connected.

Comment: The `nofail` option can be used for mounts that are not essential.